# Issue to open Page by External user

Tags: office-365, external-users

I have a site in Office 365. I have enabled External sharing on site collection.

I have shared one folder of "Documents" library with an external user. When I try to open the link (which I got in outlook email), it will behave differently. I also created one page in Pages library and shared with "**Everyone**" groups with **Read** permission.

When I open the link from an email which contains my custom page URL with source URL of shared folder URL. It is opening the page as follows:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/gxcuf89792/attachments/gxcuf89792/SharePoint_General/16263/1/Everyone%20Issue%201.png

In above image, I have put the default view of the documents library but it shows the pages library view.

With the same user when I open the /Pages/Forms/Allitems.aspx then it display as below:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/gxcuf89792/attachments/gxcuf89792/SharePoint_General/16263/2/Everyone%20Issue%202.png

I'm able to view the page in a proper way with my Office 365 user but the issue is with the External user only. Is there any issue in new view of Office 365? Please advise

Comment: both images are coming out blank?

Comment: I'm trying to upload image and it shows successfully but image is not visible in content

Comment: @AliJafer I have added links of images. Please find it

Answer (score 0):

looking at the images you have posted i can see no issue with SharePoint. With external user its restricted and the images that are not visible are to do with the site assets folder not being visible to the external users. Just give view only permission to the site asset library and you should be all set to go :)